# jQuery/jsrender - Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jsrender

Im getting an Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when ever I get to the 4th time calling my paging function getCollection(), I'm not exactly sure why the problem is happening.. if I commet out the following line:

```
jQuery('#card ul').append(template.render(data));
```

And uncomment the alert below it (for sanity), it seems to run fine past page 4.

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1 and [Boris Moore's jsrender library](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) and have never had trouble before rendering even larger data sets asynchronously.

```
var myCollection = {
  data: null,
  count: 0,
  page: 0,
  pageSize: 24
}
function getCollection(collection) {
  if (collection.length > 0) {
    var values = "",
    template = jQuery('#template');
    for (var i = myCollection.page * myCollection.pageSize; i <= ((myCollection.page + 1) * myCollection.pageSize) - 1; i += 1) {
    if (i != ((myCollection.page + 1) * myCollection.pageSize) - 1) {
        values += collection[i].card + ",";
    } else {
        values += collection[i].card;
    }
  }
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/api/cards?key=id&value=' + values,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            jQuery('#card ul').append(template.render(data));
            //alert(myCollection.page);
        }
    }
  });
  myCollection.page++;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Template is a registered keyword in javascript; don't use it.

Comment: I searched two places.  Neither had "template" as a keyword.  Are you still having the problem?

Comment: It was the registered keyword @DhaivatPandya mentioned, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Dhaivat Pandya suggested, template is a registered keyword. Thanks for the help!